# C. fread works on linux but not on windows

Tags: linux, windows

On linux this code works. It reads 50000 ints from file (file size = 200000 bytes). But in visual studio 2015 fread returns 73.
I dont undestand why?

Console:

```
Oops. Can not read successfully the stack.
 size = 50000
rsize = 73
filename = nums
Size of int = 4
Better to STOP
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Code snippet:

```
FILE* f = fopen(fn, "r");
if (f == NULL)
{
    printf("\nCan not open file  %s\n", fn);
    return 1;
}

int* stack = malloc(sizeof(int) * size);
if (stack == NULL)
{
    fclose(f);
    printf("\nCan not stack the stack - not enough memory\n");
    return 2;
}


int rsize = fread(stack, sizeof(int), size, f);
if (size != rsize)
{
    printf("\nOops. Can not read successfully the stack.\n size = %d\nrsize = %d\nfilename = %s\nSize of int = %d\nBetter to STOP\n", size, rsize, fn, sizeof(int));
    fclose(f);
    free(stack);
    return 3;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need to set binary mode "rb" when opening the file otherwise it will open as a text file (in windows) vs a binary file in linux.